# How do I use if/else shortcut to print string based on boolean value

Tags: java

I would like to print:

`Permissive mode: ON`

or

`Permissive mode: OFF`

I was trying to do it in one line like this:

```
       logMessage("Permissive mode: " +  (isPermissive == true) ? "ON" : "OFF" );
```

I could do full if/else statement and a separate variable for ON/OFF but was trying to keep it short...

Comment: You don't need the `== true`. Just: `isPermissive ? "ON" : "OFF"`.

Comment: When your code has an error, it's important to include the error message you get in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses around the conditional assignment operator `? :` because there's an addition operator before it, and [`+` has a higher precedence than `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Without the parentheses, 
    `"Permissive mode: " +  (isPermissive == true) ? "ON" : "OFF"`

is equivalent to `("Permissive mode: " +  (isPermissive == true)) ? "ON" : "OFF"`

The result of the `+` addition operator with String operands isn't a `boolean`, so the compiler will complain rightfully on the expression.

You need to surround the operator with less precedence with parentheses if you want it to evaluate first:

```
logMessage("Permissive mode: " +  (isPermissive ? "ON" : "OFF") );
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
logMessage("Permissive mode: " +  ((isPermissive) ? "ON" : "OFF"));
```

Comment: voted up for using `(  )` around the conditional expression

Comment: Downvoted for not explaining why using `( )` around the conditional expression is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can factorize it with a new method, wrapping logMessage:

```
public void myLogMessage(String message, boolean flag) {
    logMessage(message + ": " + (flag ? "ON" : "OFF"));
}
```